# How can I get the duration of *.avi *.flv,*.rmvb files in JavaScript if the uploaded file is of type *.avi or *.flv?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, media-player, media

there is my code,If the uploaded file is of type *.avi or *.flv, the duration of the file will not be sent. If it is of .wav, it’s fine.

```
<input type="file" id="input">

var vid = document.createElement('video');
 document.querySelector('#input').addEventListener('change', function() {
  // create url to use as the src of the video
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  vid.src = fileURL;
  // wait for duration to change from NaN to the actual duration
  vid.ondurationchange = function() {
    alert(this.duration);
 };
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found an answer that can be used to solve the problem https://github.com/buzz/mediainfo.js/blob/gh-pages-src/src/components/MediaInfoJs.js